# PHP images are not being displayed in bootstrap template portfolio page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem. I have downloaded a bootstrap template and uploading images in portfolio_details page. My code and this logic was working quite fine but as i changed system and transferred my files to other system, my php code in bootstrap slider stopped working. The other system has wamp server 2.5 while it was working well on wamp 2.4. I don't understand why this problem occurred! Please help me...!  My code is given below!

```
<section>
                 <div class="col-sm-8">
                     <div class="project owl-carousel">
                       <?php
                            $img_no = $_GET["image_no"];
                            $query = "SELECT * FROM `portfolio` WHERE `image_no`=".$img_no;
                            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
                               <div class="item">
                                    <?php echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='uploads/".$row['image']."'> "; ?>
                               </div>
                       <?php }; ?>

                    </div>
```

Thanks!
Regards!

Comment: what does the rendered html output source look like at that section?

Comment: empty and blank. No image is displayed in the slider. But when i write the same code in <div class="clo-sm=08">, the php code works fine and shows the images.

Comment: the source. press ctrl-u to view the page source in your browser.

Comment: ok thanks! HTML rendered source look shows that it has the image name in img sorce and the query worked fine.

Comment: push F12 to see the developer's tools console to see if you're getting any 404 or 403 errors on the images

Comment: Total 6 error of 404. The error is Failed to load resource: http://localhost/website/js/jquery/waypoints.min.js

Comment: Aside from the waypoints js, you should verify that the files actually exist in the correct folder. Are you getting 404 on the images as well?